# Hazelcast + Spring Boot + Cache Manager

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm trying to create an instance of Hazelcast client but I can't Override the Cache Manager implementation from Spring. I don't want to use a hazelcast.xml (so, I'm in a spring boot application). There is a way to do it?

Follow my test:

```
@Bean
CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new HazelcastCacheManager();
}
```

I've read many tutorials talking about this kind of implementation but this not work on Hazelcast v 3.8.1

The HazelcastCacheManager.java is an Interface not a class, so I cant initialize the interface like this... (...java basic).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two identically named objects

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.html is an interface.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/spring/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.html is a class

This example https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/springboot-caching is probably a good one to follow. Just add `hazelcast.version` to the maven properties to convent to 3.8.1.

Comment: after reading the documentation I found a lib that was missing. To access the HazelCastCacheManager.class you need to used the dependency hazelcast-spring. But they don't tell us about this lib on their documentation. hehehe. Thanks for your help and your time!